# Dynamically add and remove style based on JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript

I'm dynamically generating a `div` using JavaScript. When mouse is over certain elements in the page the new `div` appears. On mouseout it disappears. All that is working fine. But I want the `div` to be top-positioned according to the element the mouse was over of. So I record the position of the element with `getBoundingClientReach`:

```
function lopen(AbstId) {  //called OnMouseOver
    var rect = document.getElementById(AbstId).getBoundingClientRect();
    var st3="px";
    divtop = rect.top+st3 ;
    alert ("Hello :" + divtop);  //for checking purposes only

    if (this.element == null) {
        this.element = document.createElement('div');
        this.element.id = "myPopup";
        this.element.className = "myPopupBody";
        this.element.onmouseover = 'prevent()';  //if mouse over new div, do not close  
        this.element.style["top"] = divtop;   //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
    }

    document.body.appendChild(this.element);
    popUpDetails();
}

function lclose () {  //called OnMouseOut
    document.getElementById("myPopup").innerHTML = " "; 
    document.body.removeChild(this.element);
}
```

The piece of code

```
this.element.style["top"] = divtop;
```

is getting the correct top value on first event, but do not actualize for further `onmouseover` events, even though `divtop` is actually refreshing (I check with the alert of 5th line).
Does anyone spot the problem?

Comment: what is "dinamically"?

Comment: I've corrected the spelling...

Comment: Try adding position:absolute to the style of the div?

Comment: The class "myPopupBody" has position:fixed. I change to position:absolute but is not working. Thanks DNA for the editing.

Comment: Better use `this.element.onmouseover = prevent` instead of `this.element.onmouseover = 'prevent()'`.

Comment: Uh! two negative votes! Maybe is not the most interesting question, but don't believe is THAT bad either... I've been working on this for two days before posting it (I mean is not laziness)

Comment: You have to assign a function to `this.element.onmouseover`, not a string.

Comment: A function is assigned to `this.element.onmouseover` -prevent()-. The string is assign to `this.element.style["top"]`.

Comment: No. In `this.element.onmouseover = 'prevent()';`, `'prevent()'` is clearly a string, since it starts and ends with single quotes. Have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html to learn more about traditional event handling.

Answer (score 0):

Again, just for completeness. The problem was an incorrect assignment of style: top. Below the right code

```
function lopen(AbstId) {  //called OnMouseOver
    var rect = document.getElementById(AbstId).getBoundingClientRect();
    var st3="px";
    divtop = rect.top+st3 ;
    //alert ("Hello :" + divtop);  //for checking purposes only

    if (this.element == null) {
        this.element = document.createElement('div');
        this.element.id = "myPopup";
        this.element.className = "myPopupBody";
        this.element.onmouseover = 'prevent()';  //if mouse over new div, do not close  
        //this.element.style["top"] = divtop;   //here WAS my problem -deleted line
    }

    document.body.appendChild(this.element);
    document.getElementById("myPopup").style["top"] = divtop;  //here right code
    popUpDetails();
    }
```